# Spring Data DB Connection Management

Tags: spring, spring-data

If I call a Spring Repository method to query a DB, when does Spring release the connection?

I'm asking because I have a method that makes a synchronous HTTP call along with a call to a Spring Repository method. When the service I was calling out to failed, due to a timeout, I began seeing the following in our logs:

> PoolExhaustedException: [http-nio-8080-exec-47] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:15; busy:15; idle:0; lastwait:30000].

I'm assuming this is due to the connection not being release back to the pool until the method is complete, but I'm unable to find and documentation stating the mechanics of connection management.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the connection is closed when the transaction finishes, at least if you're using declarative transactions and letting Spring manage them itself. In [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-first-example), there's an example of a declarative transaction implementation:

```
public final class Boot {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml", Boot.class);
        FooService fooService = (FooService) ctx.getBean("fooService");
        fooService.insertFoo (new Foo());
    }
}
```

And that's the output you get:

```
<!-- the Spring container is starting up... -->
[AspectJInvocationContextExposingAdvisorAutoProxyCreator] - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'fooService' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors

<!-- the DefaultFooService is actually proxied -->
[JdkDynamicAopProxy] - Creating JDK dynamic proxy for [x.y.service.DefaultFooService]

<!-- ... the insertFoo(..) method is now being invoked on the proxy -->
[TransactionInterceptor] - Getting transaction for x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo

<!-- the transactional advice kicks in here... -->
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo]
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Acquired Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@a53de4] for JDBC transaction

<!-- the insertFoo(..) method from DefaultFooService throws an exception... -->
[RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[TransactionInterceptor] - Invoking rollback for transaction on x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo due to throwable [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException]

<!-- and the transaction is rolled back (by default, RuntimeException instances cause rollback) -->
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@a53de4]
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Releasing JDBC Connection after transaction
[DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at x.y.service.DefaultFooService.insertFoo(DefaultFooService.java:14)
<!-- AOP infrastructure stack trace elements removed for clarity -->
at $Proxy0.insertFoo(Unknown Source)
at Boot.main(Boot.java:11)
```

So it seems that the method releasing the connection is [`DataSourceUtils#releaseConnection`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#releaseConnection-java.sql.Connection-javax.sql.DataSource-). If you want to know what's going on with connections, you should enable the logging for this class at least.

From the other hand, I think that's the expected behaviour. You've got a long time running method which is executed transactionally, so it could be rolled back when failing, but your code is acquiring a connection each time you execute it. In order to solve your problem, you could try to **optimize the code** for your method, **not make it transactional** at all or you could **increase the maximum connection amount** for your connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I tried to release the connection with the DataSourceUtils#releaseConnection but it seams that the connection didn't end up in the connection pool because the connection holder is the container not "me"

The solution that I went with wsa just to increase the maxPoolSize in the yml file and cache the http request in the controller, but still would like to be able to just release the connection...